# Use cookie locally by using a random path (security)

Tags: cookies, security

Classic problem, a web app has secure and insecure pages (ie. account page is secure (HTTPS) and faq page is insecure (HTTP)), as a developer, I want the user to see a customized login button on the insecure pages (ie. it says 'click to login' if you are new to the site and 'Welcome User click to see your account' if you have a session.

To do this, I have secure cookies set by the server sent only when on the account page, but that account page (via jQuery) will also set an insecure cookie based on the secure one.  The insecure cookies can be used by the browser to update the login button (via Javascript).

I am using a random string (randomized on the server each time) for the path to prevent the cookie from ever being sent over the wire.  This data is just a username so it's not critical that it is completely locked down, however, it should still be guarded.

Cookie set here using jQuery (jQuery cookie plugin):

```
$.cookie('userLoggedIn', 'username', { domain: '.example.com', httpOnly: false, path: 'DFKLJGHDFDLFKHGAFDAKDJFH', expires: [one year], secure: false });
```

So far so good, but to a hacker, does path randomization work to prevent the stealing of insecure cookies?

Comment: You could avoid this entirely by setting the login/welcome text on the server side. Is there a reason you can't/don't want to do that?

Comment: Two reasons: 1) I would still need those cookies sent over the wire over HTTP and 2) Performance:  it requires an HTTP request each time vs the user getting a cached page

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is a very old question, but I will try to answer it.

Yes and No.

It doesn't necessarily need to be completely random - the only reason for it to be random is to make sure user never tries to get to that url, nor any ajax request goes there. To make sure that happens, you can use e.g. an UUID in the path.

You also need to make sure you control ALL of the JS on your domain.

That way the cookie will never get sent over the wire (the only way for it to get sent over the wire is for your JS to read it off `document.cookie` property and attach it or somehow send a request for that randomised URL).

A hacker won't be able to read the cookie, because browsers protect cookies from JS executed from other domains (protocol://domain:port combination has to match).

So the only way left to read off the cookie is to have access to the machine, then cookies can be read from disc as it is saved as plain text. But there are way more security vulnerabilities that come with having access to the user account.

So to answer your question, it is quite secure, but you have to keep in mind the vulnerabilities that come with such a solution.